# How to deploy a sharded cluster in kubernetes with 2 nodes and 3 replicas and 4 mongos?

Tags: database, mongodb, kubernetes, clustered-index

I need to create a sharded cluster on k8 using archives yaml. I have just one idea but I have problems with the shards then I want to found another option. Taking in account that to create the sharded cluster also use statefulsets.

Help me please

Comment: Have you read the official tutorial? https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster/

Comment: no le entiendo bien